# F#'s fshtmldoc.exe using Mono/OS X

Tags: f#, mono, powerpack

This is doubtless something obvious, but downloading the F# PowerPack from codeplex and running fshtmldoc produces this error:

```
clements$ mono ./fshtmldoc.exe FSharp.PowerPack.dll
Processing 'FSharp.PowerPack.dll'...
Unexpected failure while writing HTML docs: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.AssemblyLoader
```

This is using mono 2.6.3, F# 2.0 1.9.9.9, & OS X 10.6.3 on a 32-bit intel processor.
Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

John Clements

(repost from powerpack online discussion group--no response there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At IntelliFactory we are so fed up with fshtmldoc.exe that we started an alternative project:

https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/if-doc

It is still in beta but it quickly approaching being useful. I have not tried it on Mono yet but am interested in supporting it on Mono.

The key difference between our tool and fshtmldoc is that our tool uses Mono.Cecil instead of linking to the assemblies being documented. This means that it does not fail when those assemblies are in a different folder or their references are missing.